# Possible to WooCommerce delay completed order email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to delay the WooCommerce completed order email by 2 days. Meaning that the completed order email will only be sent 48 hours after a shop manager (or admin) marks an order as completed.
Is there a way to do this? If someone could point me in the right direction as to where to look, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is the business reason for this delay? Is it awaiting shipment or something similar?

Comment: i just costumize my woocommerce for user registration, and i want to automatic screening, and They will be able to email after 2 days after registration

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this could be disabling default WooCommerce email scheduling and then rescheduling custom emails on order completed or for desired action.